# What Does This Loop Optimization Profile Mean?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization

I am getting started using VTune.  As an educational example, I'm trying my hand at some micro-optimization in debug mode.  Here's a toy example from my codebase.  This code appears in a C++ non-`const` method, and ".data_length" is an `int` field of the object (offset 32 bytes), typically a large number:

```
for (int i=0;i<data_length;++i) { /*...*/ }
```

VTune helpfully showed me the assembly (from MSVC 2013) for the for loop.  Note the performance numbers, in seconds (I removed all the timings that don't register).  I also added some annotation:

```
0x140433084 mov dword ptr [rsp+0x588], 0x0 |       | ;"i=0"
0x14043308f jmp 0x1404330a1 <Block 77>     |       | ;jump to compare and loop body
                                           |       |
0x140433091 Block 76:                      |       | ;"++i"
0x140433091 mov eax, dword ptr [rsp+0x588] | 0.451 |
0x140433098 inc eax                        | 0.002 |
0x14043309a mov dword ptr [rsp+0x588], eax |       |
                                           |       |
0x1404330a1 Block 77:                      |       | ;if (!(i<data_length)) goto next section
0x1404330a1 mov rax, qword ptr [rsp+0x6f0] | 0.407 |
0x1404330a9 mov eax, dword ptr [rax+0x20]  |       | ;  move "data_length" into "eax".
0x1404330ac cmp dword ptr [rsp+0x588], eax | 1.195 | ;  "i<data_length;"
0x1404330b3 jnl 0x140433106 <Block 80>     |       |
0x1404330b5 Block 78:                      |       |
. . .                                      |       | ;Loop body.  There's a jmp in here to
                                           |       | ;  block 76.
                                           |       |
0x140433106 Block 80:                      |       | ;code following loop
```

What this tells me is that loading `i` to increment it is incurring a caching failure (why isn't a register, geez?).  Second, that the test logic is pretty sluggish--especially loading ".data_length" each time.

---

I figured, why not load it once and then use decrement:

```
for (int i=data_length-1;i>=0;--i) { /*...*/ }
```

The assembly and timing look like:

```
0x140433084 mov rax, qword ptr [rsp+0x6f0] |       | ;Same code, but now only happens once!
0x14043308c mov eax, dword ptr [rax+0x20]  |       |
0x14043308f dec eax                        |       | ;"data_length-1"
0x140433091 mov dword ptr [rsp+0x588], eax |       | ;"i=data_length-1;"
0x140433098 jmp 0x1404330aa <Block 77>     |       | ;jump to compare and loop body
                                           |       |
0x14043309a Block 76:                      |       | ;"++i"
0x14043309a mov eax, dword ptr [rsp+0x588] | 0.357 |
0x1404330a1 dec eax                        | 0.002 |
0x1404330a3 mov dword ptr [rsp+0x588], eax |       |
                                           |       |
0x1404330aa Block 77:                      |       | ;if (i<0) goto next section
0x1404330aa cmp dword ptr [rsp+0x588], 0x0 | 0.401 | ;  "i>=0;"
0x1404330b2 jl 0x140433105 <Block 80>      | 2.806 |
0x1404330b4 Block 78:                      |       |
. . .                                      |       | ;Loop body.  Same as above, I think.
                                           |       |
0x140433105 Block 80:                      |       | ;code following loop
```

Look at that `jl`!  Three seconds for a jump?  I thought maybe the location wasn't in the instruction cache, but as you can see it's actually quite close (right after the loop body, as you'd expect).  More importantly, the first method should have the same problem anyway.  The first version's `jnl` didn't even register.

My guess is that its timing is getting eaten up in the loop body--although it's weird that it happens in one case but not the other.  Do I have more work to do looking in to that?

I wrote all this, and now looking again I think it may be a boring branch prediction issue.  CPUs like to take branches backward in loops, but in this case the branch to block 80 *shouldn't* be taken most of the time.

---

I'm definitely still learning this, so assuming I annotated everything mostly correctly, I have a few questions:

1. Am I right in thinking that `i` should probably be a register, and that it will become one in optimized mode?
2. Whatever is happening with that `jl` in the second version?  Is it indeed a branch prediction fail?  Why doesn't it show up on the next instruction?

---

Edit: The CPU this is being tested on is an Intel 990X (Gulftown, 2011).

Comment: Trying to optimise the generated code in debug mode is a waste of time.  You need to be using release mode.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know. That's why this is a "toy example" for "educational" purposes. Gotta walk before you run.

Answer (score 0):

`i` should probably be in a register (e.g. if the compiler optimised); however it's also possible that the code in the loop body (not shown) uses all the registers and that it's better for performance to avoid putting `i` in a register (especially if that loop body contains an inner loop or function call or something).

I have no idea what your CPU is (VIA, AMD, Intel; Atom, Xeon; how old), but the branch prediction in modern CPUs should handle that branch well. However you could maybe expect a branch mis-prediction when the loop terminates, and if the number of iterations is low (e.g. `data_length-1` is small) that single mis-prediction might be significant.

Comment: Neat.  So what's causing `jl` to be so much slower if it's not branch misprediction? The very smallest `data_length-1` could be is `2^10-1`. It's typically `2^14-1`. See edit; this is an Intel 990X.